# Show revelent tab when the respective link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

What i have

I have a item in navbar called "About Us" & it has two sub items > Profile & Vision but i have one page named profilevision.html which has two divs profile & vision along with two buttons profile & vision when profile is clicked jq shows profile div & hides vision div

What i want to do

when on page other than profilevison.html if from the navbar vision is clicked i want to load profilevison.html to load with vision div visible & profile div hidden

What i tried

I can't think of any thing

Ok i'll try to be clear

visit this site [enter link description here](http://kwebmakerusa.com/gciint/01102015/)

on the home page there is a navbar which has about us with two sub items profile & vision clicking on anyone of them open the page profilevision.html [enter link description here](http://kwebmakerusa.com/gciint/01102015/profilevision.html) which has two divs profile & vision vision is hidden by default i have two onclick events for two buttons on right which show it's respective tab. Now what i want is if from the home page if i click vision i want to show vision tab & hide profile tab

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what it is that you want. Could you try rewording that a little bit? Take your time, and be as concise as you can.

Comment: @wrxsti edited the question hope i have written correctly this time

Comment: If you want help here you need to show code. ie: what you've tried already. Nobody is going to hand you a solution without an attempt.

Comment: @JaredEitnier He sent some links. My guess is he is still relatively new to HTML and jQuery, and genuinely had no idea which direction to go for this, or how to even word a search for this kind of thing.

Comment: @JaredEitnier i have no idea of how to do this other i would have posted this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the links of Profile to:

```
http://kwebmakerusa.com/gciint/01102015/profilevision.html?section=profile
```

and the link of Vision to:

```
http://kwebmakerusa.com/gciint/01102015/profilevision.html?section=vision
```

and add this script to your website:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("profile") > -1) {
    $( ".profiletab" ).trigger( "click" );
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf("vision") > -1) {
    $( ".visiontab" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

This code checks if the url contains profile and if it contains profile it triggers during load time the click of li.profiletab (which then shows only profile tab section), same thing if the url contains vision.

Comment: Just a thought, but wouldn't both conditions return TRUE since the name of the file is profilevision.html? The file name contains both strings.

Comment: Yeah forgot, it would be found in both cases so, first of all ... the file name should be changed too, probably aboutus.html

Anyway this is my solution, there are better ways to handle this ofcurse, for example by using id's like this:

http://kwebmakerusa.com/gciint/01102015/profilevision.html#visiontab and http://kwebmakerusa.com/gciint/01102015/profilevision.html#profiletab ...

Answer (score 1):

You have three options that I see available.

**1)** Make them two different files that have the needed default visible (profile.html & vision.html)

or

**2)** You could attempt to embed a string into the URL that you could then pull a substring from to determine which should be visible. A brief example below:

**Navbar Links**

```
<ul class="drops" style="display: none;">
    <li class="profiletab"><a href="profilevision.html?default=profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="visiontab"><a href="profilevision.html?default=vision">Vision</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in the profilevision.html document you could run a ready script like this.

```
$(function(){
    var defaultView = window.location.split('?default=')[1];
    if(defaultView == 'vision'){
        $('.vis').show();
        $('.pro').hide();
    }
});
```

This code isn't tested but it should get close.

**3)** Another option would be to use cookies to store this variable and then on page load pull that cookie to see which should be loaded by default. Here is a good place to get started with cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

A basic example would be something like:

```
$('ul.drops li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.cookie('defaultView', $(this).text());
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Then for your conditional:

```
$(function(){
    if($.cookie('defaultView') == 'Vision'){
        $('.vis').show();
        $('.pro').hide();
        $.removeCookie('defaultView');
    }
});
```

**Side Note**

Typically when you find yourself doing something like this it isn't a good thing. I myself would call this a bit of a hack job to counter a design flaw. Consider looking into server side generated content. You would be surprised at how much control you would have over situations just like this one.

Comment: what method would you follow ? i am learning jquery & trying to practice it in every way/everywhere possible.

Comment: I would probably go the route of using cookies. When you click the link, it would store the cookie saving whether profile or vision was clicked. Once profilevision.html is loaded, then pull that cookie value, and use a similar conditional statement to the one above to show the appropriate div.

Comment: @Kalpesh I updated the answer to show a brief example of how you could use the library I linked to make cookies do this.